# SAS Sequential (Hierarchical) Regression: Change in R2 between models and F test

Tags: sas, regression

I am wanting to perform Sequential (Hierarchical) Regression in SAS where I dictate the clusters of variables added to the model.  I'd then like to see the change in R2 (R square) between the models and an F test for significance.

Here's example syntax of the models I'd like to compare:

```
proc reg data=pt8;
    Covariates: model y=jz lnWg iq;
    Linear: model y=R RM jz lnWg iq;
    Quadratic: model y=R RM RM2 R2 RInt jz lnWg iq;
run;
quit;
```

Is there a way to use ANOVA or the built-in forward selection where I can dicatate how I'm adding variables ({R, RM} for the "Linear" model and then {RM2, R2, RInt} for the "Quadratic" model)?  Your syntax is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to fit a Hierarchical Linear Model (HLM), or are you trying to specify the model to include multiple variables at a time for selection (e.g. `proc logistic`'s "hierarchy=multiple" option)?

Comment: Not, HLM, just sequential regression.  Sometimes this is referred to as hierarchical regression (but not h. linear r.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `include=` statement to force certain variable into the model when it does forward selection. You can get a summary table of the models with the `ods output` statement. Make sure that you have `ods graphics on` set, and `noprint` is not used in `PROC REG`.

```
proc reg data=pt8;
    Covariates: model y=jz lnWg iq / selection = forward;
    Linear: model y=R RM jz lnWg iq / selection = forward include=2;
    Quadratic: model y=R RM RM2 R2 RInt jz lnWg iq / selection=forward include=5;
    ods output SelectionSummary;
run;
```

`include` is an integer that tells `PROC REG` to keep the first *n* variables into the model, then perform forward selection on the remaining variables. You will also have a table named `SelectionSummary` with fit statistics for each model and step in the selection process.

Alternatively, you can group variables with curly brackets, and `PROC REG` will treat them all as one provided they meet certain tolerance values and don't make the matrix singular. It automatically removes the variable that breaks the model if this is the case. You can optionally name those groups with `groupnames=`.

```
proc reg data=pt8;
    Covariates: model y=jz lnWg iq / selection = forward;
    Linear: model y={R RM} jz lnWg iq / selection = forward;
    Quadratic: model y={R RM RM2 R2 RInt} jz lnWg iq / selection=forward;
    ods output SelectionSummary;
run;
```

If you have interaction effects that you would like to measure, `PROC GLMSELECT` has many more options than `PROC REG` for how you'd like to add or remove those effects. Just don't forget to turn on the `showpvalues` option - it's the only procedure where they don't show *p*-values by default. What, you mean you *don't* know every probability from every type of *F* distribution? :)

Comment: Thanks very much--this is progress, but it still lacks the simplicity of the change in R2 for each sequential group of variables entered in a table.  [Here](http://justinwiegand.com/want.png) is an example of what I'd like to see for a similar equation.

Comment: Updated to include a way to get a table that has the model selection information. You'll need to do some minor additional coding to get things like the change in R^2.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these methods work to only include the specific variables desired to be entered.  They still work stepwise with all the variables in each step.